# F# example - why does it work

Tags: f#, fibonacci

On [English wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_Sharp_(programming_language)) there is a code example in F#

```
/// Fibonacci Number formula
let rec fib n =
    match n with
    | 0 | 1 -> n
    | _ -> fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)
```

Why does this example work for fib(1)?

Comment: Working fine: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JPpRlx

Answer (score 7):

The code says that if `n` is "`0` or `1`" then result is `n`(this is the part : `0|1 -> n`)

Otherwise it will be : `fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)`

So for `fib(1)`, `n=1` so the result is `1`, there will be no recursion.